# EXC_BAD using own struct as return value

Tags: objective-c, struct, exc-bad-access

i am using the following struct as a return value of a method:

```
typedef struct {
CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCorner;
CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCorner;
} LCMapBoundings;
```

The following method crashes instantly:

```
-(LCMapBoundings)calculate {
NSLog(@"test");
}
```

But that one works:

```
-(LCMapBoundings*)calculate {
NSLog(@"test");
}
```

Why is that? What am i messing up when using the first method?

Comment: Post some code on how you're using it. And it's not a function, it's a method.

Comment: I am just calling [self calculate];. All contents of the method are commented out. Changing the return type makes the app crash or not.

Comment: shadow are you using malloc to allocate the object or declaring it on the stack?

Comment: if you're using `[self calculate]`, why are you returning something? It ends up discarded, right?

Comment: My intention was to return something. But when it crashed i started to debug and reduced it to that code above to identify the problem.

Comment: @Jesus Ramos: Actually i'm doing nothing. I declared the method above only. Without any content. Just the declaration makes the app crash.

Comment: You have a crash? **POST THE CRASH**  You have compiler warnings (Yes, you do)?  **FIX THEM OR POST THEM**  It is impossible to answer questions like this without more diagnostic information and the IDE is assuredly given exactly that to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's crashing because you don't return a value in your method? That's undefined behaviour.